# Android - Cannot change layout using v4 Fragments

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, visibility, oncreate

My users should be able to change (using preferences) how the interface looks like (visually enabling and disabling certain layouts dynamically) in my app.

I'm working with the v4 ViewPager (PagerTabStrip to be exact) and am trying to change this in the onResume() method, right after the user closes the "settings menu" to return to the app.

I can change variables this way, but cannot seem to change anything layoutwise (I used to work with TabHosts, where this worked perfectly). If I call this method in the onCreateView() method, everything works fine, but I don't want my users to force close the app before any changes can be visible.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    vContainer = container; // global variable
    switch (mCurrentPage) {
    case 1:
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lifepoints_layout,
                container, false);
        // irrelevant code
        InputStyleType = (LinearLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.llInputEditText);
        InputStyleButtons = (TableLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tlInputButtons);

        InitializePreferences(); // <- this method
        break;
    case 2:
        // irrelevant code
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

This works perfectly, as it should. However, when the code gets called via the onResume(), the program crashes!

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isPaused)
        InitializePreferences();
    isPaused = false;
}
```

This is the method itself:

```
public void InitializePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences getPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    prefInput = getPreferences.getBoolean("pref_input", true);
    prefFb = getPreferences.getBoolean("pref_fb", false);

    if (prefInput) {
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. It seems I cannot change anything layoutwise unless it's directly called from the onCreateView, which doesn't seem right.

**EDIT 1**

I've analysed my method completely, it gets called correctly and I've tested with some variables. Everything works fine until I'm trying to change something that is visible to the user (toasts work perfectly fine).

**EDIT 3**

Deleted Edit 2 and this is where my code stands at the moment. It's still not working, and it's actually a bit of a mess. I do think the answer isn't far off.

```
public void InitializePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences getPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    prefInput = getPreferences.getBoolean("pref_input", true);
    prefFb = getPreferences.getBoolean("pref_fb", false);

    if (isPaused) {
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lifepoints_layout, vContainer,
                false);

        InputStyleType = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llInputEditText);
        InputStyleButtons = (TableLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tlInputButtons);

        InputStyleType.invalidate();
        InputStyleButtons.invalidate();
    }

    if (prefInput) {
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the log cat with the errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invalidate your views. Try adding `InputStyleType.invalidate()` and `InputStyleButtons.invalidate()` to the InitializePreferences method. You might need to also invalidate the view parent(s) that contain InputStyleType and InputStyleButtons.

**EDIT:** Try this in the onResume() callback:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.lifepoints_layout,
            container_2, false);
```

To make this work create a global ViewGroup variable and set it's value to the value of `container` in the onCreateView callback.

```
container_2 = container;
```

Comment: I've added the code, but it doesn't seem to work. As I'm not familiar with this particular piece of code, I'm probably doing something wrong myself.

Comment: Well, I'm about 99% sure that your problem is because a view isn't being updated. Try re-inflating the view (like in onCreateView()) in the onResume() method. See if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Could you give me an example? As I'm still struggling. Perhaps with the code above? Anyway, thnx for the help

Comment: You're welcome. Ok. I put up an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you still having the same problem? Also, did you try re-inflating the layout like in my example?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my edit. The app doesn't crash anymore, so that's a good thing, but still nothing happens. I can't change the visibility when InitializePreferences() is called from onResume().

Comment: I've also found that InputStyleButtons.invalidate() and InputStyleType.invalidate() does nothing, or at least not that I've noticed.

Comment: Ok. This would be my best guess. I'm thinking that pref input keeps returning true. Put some `System.out.println()`s in both the if and else code where you set the visibility of InputStyleType and InputStyleButtons. So: 

    `if (prefInput) {
        System.out.println("IF");
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        System.out.println("ELSE");
        InputStyleButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        InputStyleType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`

If that is it then you've found your problem.

Comment: I'm receiving both IF and ELSE in my logcat when switching the views in my settings menu. prefInput is a bool that changes when the user tries to access the settings. They can choose between one view and the other.
When pressing the back button (returning to the activity and calling the onResume() method) the changes would be instantly visible.
However, that was before I worked with Fragments. Now I'm working with the v4 PagerTabStrip and it didn't work anymore.

Comment: It still works when calling it from the onCreate(), so I know InitializePreferences() works just fine, but calling it from the onResume() (which is non-UI, I think I read something about that, but I don't know if it's relevant) doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: It might be a bug. I honestly can't see anything that you're doing wrong. My last guess would be other code that is affecting the view somehow? Other than that, I really don't know.